# Using DKIM records in Wordpress PHPMailer in a way that it survives an WP update

Tags: wordpress, phpmailer, dkim

Has someone found a solution for using the DKIM option in PHPMailer to send emails DKIM signed without editing wp-core files?

The PHPMailer has public properties that start with $DKIM_ that can be used to send messages DKIM-signed. I know how to do that. I can hardcode the values in the PHPMailer.php file, which will work until WP gets updated and overwrites these changes.

I've also looked at /wp-includes/pluggable.php which calls the PHPMailer class but cannot find a way to hook into that to set the right DKIM property values.

Is there a plugin or another solution?

Best regards,
Pieter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can get your hands on the PHPMailer instance that WordPress uses via the `phpmailer_init` hook, and you can save your hook code as part of your site's `functions.php` file, which will survive updates. [Docs are here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-PHPMailer-in-WordPress), and a basic example is:

```php
add_action('phpmailer_init', function ($mailer){
  $mailer->isSMTP();
  $mailer->Host = "mail.example.com"; // your SMTP server
  $mailer->Port = 25;
  $mailer->SMTPDebug = 2;
  $mailer->CharSet  = "utf-8";
  //etc
});
```

You can set your DKIM params in there too.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without editing files directly with the WPCode plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/

Install the plugin and activate, then create a new snippet.  Make sure the type is "PHP Snippet" in the dropdown selector, then paste in the following, replacing your details

```php
add_action('phpmailer_init', function (\PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer $mail) {
    $mail->DKIM_domain = 'example.com';
    $mail->DKIM_private = '/path/to/your/private/key.private';
    $mail->DKIM_selector = 'domainselector';
    $mail->DKIM_passphrase = 'privatekeypassword';
    $mail->DKIM_identity = $mail->From;
    return $mail;
});
```

Generating the DKIM can be done with

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -passout pass:privatekeypassword -out key.private 2048
openssl rsa -in key.private -pubout > key.public
```

(making sure to replace `privatekeypassword` with something safer, and change in the PHP snippet)

Creating the DKIM record in your DNS is done as a TXT record with the name

```
domainselector._domainkey.example.com
```

and the value

```
v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=
```

and add the bit after the `p=` with the contents of `key.public` without the "begin/end public key" lines, and with all newlines removed

Replace `domainselector` in the TXT key value with the same value as in the `$mail->DKIM_SELECTOR` in PHP.